# How to sort multiple partitions by their drive in Explorer's This PC window?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, sorting

I have multiple partitions from 3 HDDs. Is there a way to sort them by the HDD they're on?

I tried Sort by, but didn't work.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx5Ln.png)

Comment: Try to sort by File System.

Comment: Didn't work, they are still mixed.